# Error when trying to redirect from _Layout page in ASP.NET Core MVC Razor

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm fairly new to .NET Core having worked on older .NET versions like Windows forms. I have a nav bar set up in my `_Layout` page which I want to use to redirect to other Razor pages.

For example I have a `Home` page (`index.cshtml`) in a folder called `Home` off of my `Views` folder. If I want to select Customer Search option from the nav bar I use an onclick event which calls the function below.

```
function SearchClick() {
    window.location.href = "CustomerSearchView.cshtml";
    return false;
}
```

The `CustomerSearchView` is in a `CustomerSearch` folder below the `Home` folder in `Views`. There is also a `CustomerSearchController` with the code

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

If I try to add the path into the browser such as `https://localhost:7022/CustomerSearchView.cshtml` I get the error

> This localhost page can’t be found - no webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7022/CustomerSearchView.cshtml

I have tried all sort of variations using the full path with `Views/CustomerSearch` and others but get the same error.

I'm not familiar with the routing procedure and I'm not sure what mistake I'm making and I thought it would save time to ask and would be really happy if someone could point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by correcting the routing and adding the following code to my program.cs

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "customersearch",
    pattern: "{controller=CustomerSearchController}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "CustomerSearchController", action = 
"Index" });
```

When adding any new views with controllers simply add the equivalent routing code for it to make it visible to the project.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function SearchClick() {
    window.location.href = "/CustomerSearch/Index";
    return false;
}
```